# Codeigniter ActiveRecord, select CONCAT AS

Tags: mysql, sql, codeigniter

I am new in CodeIgniter Active Record

I need help converting this SQL query

```
SELECT w.PATIENT, 
CONCAT( 'Bed',' ',h.BED_NO ,' ', 'in' ,' ','Room',  h.ROOM_NO ) AS Location,
DATEDIFF(h.ALLOWED_DATE,w.WAITING_DATE) AS Duration  
FROM W w left outer join D d on w.Do=d.Do left outer join H h on w.P=h.P
WHERE w.patient=$_SESSION['user']`
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [**Active Record**](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html) you can do so

```
$this->db->select("w.PATIENT,
CONCAT( 'Bed',' ',h.BED_NO ,' ', 'in' ,' ','Room',  h.ROOM_NO )AS Location,
DATEDIFF(h.ALLOWED_DATE,w.WAITING_DATE) AS Duration
",FALSE);
$this->db->from('W w');
$this->db->join('D d ','w.Do=d.Do ','LEFT');
$this->db->join('H h',' w.P=h.P','LEFT');
$this->db->where('w.patient',$_SESSION['user']);
$result=$this->db->get();
```

Comment: Thanks but I have error(Undefined variable: count),how do I display the result in view?; this is my control: '$this->load->model('M_model');
$query=$this->M_model->P();
$data['count']=$query;'                                            and my view: '<?php foreach ($count as $row):?>
                <td><?php echo $row->patient;  ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row->Duration;  ?></td>
            </table>
            <?php endforeach; ?>'

Comment: @user3492826 can you update your question with the problem details and the code you are trying

Comment: @M Khalid Junaid, thank you it works for now,in case of any issue i will let u know.rgds